# SwiftUI PlaygroundBook I can't access the other View

Tags: swiftui, swift-playground

I cannot access GameView from WelcomeView.  How can I get page Navigation in Playground Book ?

**Error**

```
Cannot find "Game View" in scope
```

**Welcome View**

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct WelcomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GameView()
    }
}
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(WelcomeView())
```

**Game View**

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct GameView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("GameView")
    }
}
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(GameView())
```

**Welcome View Image**

[image]

**Game View Image**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `public` access level to your classes/properties/methods/properties. With that you can access them from your **main** playground.

---

```
public struct GameView: View {

  public init() { }

  public var body: some View {
    Text("GameView")
  }
}
```